# Best way to list where everywhere a module has been included

Tags: ruby, module

Of course, to achieve what I ask for in the title, it is possible to write the following code:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def included receiver
      my_herd << receiver
    end

    def my_herd; @my_herd ||= [] end
    alias where_everywhere_am_I_included my_herd
  end
end

Foo.where_everywhere_am_I_included #=> []

module Bar
  include Foo
end

Foo.where_everywhere_am_I_included #=> [Bar]
# etc.
```

I can imagine *worse* ways to do this, such as to search `ObjectSpace` for all the modules and grep their ancestries. What I want to know, is there a better way? Am I forgetting something, such as something like method `Module#included_in`. Am I missing something clever with eg. famous `#append_features` method? Whath better alternatives do I have?

**Edited:** The real world problem I am solving is related to [my library SY](https://github.com/boris-s/sy), which provides physical unit methods. Physical unit methods, such as `1.metre`, `1.m`, `1.s`, `1.lb`, `1.K`, tend to be simple symbols prone to collisions. Eg. `ActiveSupport` already defines time methods `#hour`, `#minute`, `#second` on `Numeric`. SY also defines methods `#hour` alias `#h`, `#minute` alias `#min`, `#second` alias `#s` on `Numeric` by the means of a mixin providing `#method_missing` reacting to the unit methods. But people who use `ActiveSupport` already have `#hour`, `#minute`, `#second` defined and therefore `#method_missing` won't kick in. They still can access `SY` methods by `#h`, `#min`, `#s` abbreviations, but that's besides the point. The point is, that people should be warned when the mixin finds possible collisions in the modules in which it is included. That would be simply achieved by coding the collision check in the `Module#included` hook. But the problem is that the user may also define the unit dynamically, such as:

```
PINT = Unit.of Volume, amount: 568.26.cm³
QUART = Unit.of Volume, amount: 2.pint
```

But one can imagine that the user already has the method `#quart` defined on `Numeric`, doing something else, such as computing 1 quarter of the receiver, or returning 4th musical interval relative to the receiver etc. So when ze calls `QUART = Unit#of...` constructor, I want to ask the mixin [`SY::ExpressibleInUnits`](https://github.com/boris-s/sy/blob/master/lib/sy/expressible_in_units.rb) to report where everywhere has it been mixed in, and warn after seeing the collision in `Numeric`. I simply want to save my user from surprises and I'm wondering what is the most virtuous (using [Avdi](https://github.com/avdi)'s trademark word) way to do it.

Comment: Don't know about a better way than overriding `Module.included` method. Btw. are you trying to solve some real problem or just playing with ruby ?

Comment: It does not really matter, because as Matz said, Ruby is to make the programmers happy. But I actually do happen to be solving a real problem here. It has been just a few days ago when, after reading the code of many other projects, I realized that my [SY library](https://github.com/boris-s/sy), along with [phys-units](https://github.com/masa16/phys-units), is the best physical units system in Ruby. So I am trying to behave responsibly. Physical unit methods, such as `1.metre`, `1.m`, `1.s`, `1.lb`, `1.K` etc. are frequently short words prone to method collisions. (I'll just edit the OP).

Comment: In terms of your real world problem, you could use `method_added` and report collisions there.

Comment: Thanks! I hope I'll see more suggestions like this. Make yours a full-fledged answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: My feeling nowadays is that `SY::Metre.new(1)` or `SY::Metre(1)` would be far preferable to `1.metre` for two reasons: 1) it avoids the type of clobbering that you're trying to deal with 2) It's absolutely clear what the intention is, and what type is the result. YMMV. +1 for a well written question though. I'll be interested to see the answers.

Comment: +1, I'll make it optional then. But I'm dogfooding it to myself in my biological library, and I tell you, I have so many expressions like `1.µM.s⁻¹` on one line, that I do appreciate the direct unit methods despite all their clobber. Btw. the syntax for what you said is `SY::METRE` for 1 metre, and `2 * SY::METRE` or `SY::Length.magnitude( 2 )` for 2 metres...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `method_added` would allow you to provide a warning in your real world scenario.

```
module MethodAdded
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(method_name)
      if method_name == :my_magic
        puts 'So sorry you did not like my code, it will not bother you now'
      end
    end
  end
end


class Something
  include MethodAdded

  def my_magic
    'I can create this method without worries.'
  end
end
```

---

Here's an example of an unlikely risk of extending ClassMethods that I mention in the comments.

```
module ClassMethods
  def self.extended(base)
    puts 'I am going to do all sorts of evil stuff now'
  end
end

module MethodAdded
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClaszMethods  #Intentional typo to demonstrate "risk"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this will definitely help to catch the method definitions coming _after_ the `SY`'s includes, that's another headache of mine, what if the user requires `ActiveSupport` or something else _after_ `require 'sy'`...

Comment: A small question: Is it totally safe to say `base.extend( ClassMethods )`? Is it really of no use to say `base.extend( MethodAdded::ClassMethods )`?

Comment: The only risk I can think of is if you don't define `ClassMethods` in your module, then it would use `::ClassMethods` if it exists which could cause you problems.  See the edit for an example.  It's really not a risk that I worry about.

Comment: Since it does not seem I'm going to get any other answer, let me express finally thanks for help to you and everyone else who read the question. I was able to implement roughly 30% of the desired warning functionality on the same day and even discovered some hidden bugs in the process. `method_added` is definitely to be used, although it turns out to be quite tricky. I wouldn't have thought about it myself.